# How can we assign order by in dynamicly?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I my UI I have drop down to sort some filed ascending or descending order.
I have written my JPA query like below:

```
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Integer>
{
@Query("select DISTINCT T from Task T where T.status = ? order by  T.priority ? , T.location ?")
    List<Task> findByStatus(String status,String prioritySortBy,String locationSortBy);
    
}
```

here prioritySortBy can be ASC or DESC
similarly locationSortBy can be ASC or DESC

But here I am getting below error :
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ? near line 1, column 290 [select DISTINCT T from com.deere.dsfj.taskmanager.bean.Task T, com.deere.dsfj.taskmanager.bean.TaskGroupTypeMapping TM, com.deere.dsfj.taskmanager.bean.TaskType TT where T.taskType.taskTypeId=TM.taskTypeId and TM.taskTypeId =?  and TM.taskGroupId = ? and T.status = ? order by  T.priority ? , T.location ?]

Comment: Use `Pageable` or at least `Sort` as a method argument and ditch the query. Something like `findByStatus(String status, Sort ordering)`.

Comment: any sample code for reference  ?

Comment: That is already in my comment, nothing more nothing less.

Comment: I am getting compile error The method by(List<Sort.Order>) is undefined for the type Sort: service code is List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

  Order order1 = new Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "priority");
  orders.add(order1);

  Order order2 = new Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "location");
  orders.add(order2);
  
  taskRepository.findByStatus(status,Sort.by(orders)).forEach(task -> taskList.add(task));   repo method @Query("select DISTINCT T from Task T where T.status = ? ")
 List<Task> findByStatus(String status,Sort sort);

Comment: Ditch the `@Query` as I stated. And you get a compilation error because there is no `by` method on `Sort` at least **not** the version you are using.